# Jump to new paragraph and insert data

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I´m checking if the line, my cursor is currently in is empty. If not, my code shall add a range after the current and insert data there.

The new paragraph is inserted correctly but how can I jump there to insert my data?

This is my code so far:

```
private void PasteInNewLine()
{
    Word.Range cursorPosition = GetCurrentRange();
    cursorPosition.InsertParagraphAfter();
    cursorPosition.GoToNext(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine).Paste(); // wrong
    cursorPosition.Next();
    cursorPosition.Paste(); // also wrong
}

private Word.Range GetCurrentRange()
{
    object start = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range.Sentences.First.Start;
    object end = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range.Sentences.Last.End;
    return Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(ref start, ref end);
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't at all clear. Stack Overflow is supposed to be a repository of questions and answers to help "everyone", so it's important that the information is clear. By "line [that is] currently empty do you really mean a line (meaning Shift+Enter was pressed), or a paragraph (Enter was pressed)? Or something else? And "add a range after the current": do you mean insert a new paragraph? I think I can give you more efficient code if the question is clear...

Answer (score 0):

Got it ...

```
cursorPosition.InsertParagraphAfter();
cursorPosition = cursorPosition.Next();
cursorPosition.GoToPrevious(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine).Paste();
```

did the trick